# How to compare date with date that stored in database in php

Tags: php, mysql

How can I compare date with date that was stored in database.
for example I have 2 dates(date1 and date2) in format date and I want to get dates that are between these dates(date1< I need these dates

How can I compare these dates in select query?

I use this query but it doesn't work:

```
   $sql="select name from person where date <'$from_date'";
   $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
   if(!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
   {
    die('error' .mysqli_error($con));
   }
```

Comment: share some sample data please.  generally, don't store dates in your DB, this problem is trivial if you instead stored timestamps.

Comment: I believe you’re looking for the `AND` keyword. You’re half-way there yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the BETWEEN statement.

```
WHERE date BETWEEN 'Older Date Here' AND 'Newer Date Here'
```

Answer (score 0):

For compatibility, format your dates in ISO mode ("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.xxx").  You can leave off the whole time portion, or just the milliseconds, or the seconds and milliseconds.    When passed as literals in an SQL query, they should be single-quoted strings.

Today is:   `'2013-07-12'`
Right now is:  `'2013-07-12 13:38:03'`